# How to find max value between boundary in segmentation?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

here's an issue: I want to find actual maximum width of boundary in segmented image with irregular shape ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upXV3.png))
below I post some example image I use for testing
So far I managed to obtain boundaries and skeleton line, but how do I measure distance between contours perpendicural to the skeleton line?

```
def get_skeleton(image_path):

  im = cv2.imread(img_path , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  binary = im > filters.threshold_otsu(im)
  skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(binary)
  return skeleton

skeleton = get_skeleton(img_path)
plt.imshow(skeleton, cmap="gray")

def get_boundary(image_path):
  reading_Img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  reading_Img = cv2.cvtColor(reading_Img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  canny_Img = cv2.Canny(reading_Img,90,100)
  contours,_ = cv2.findContours(canny_Img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  canvas = np.zeros_like(reading_Img)
  boundary = cv2.drawContours(canvas , contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
  return boundary

boundary = get_boundary(img_path)
plt.imshow(boundary)
```

[Sample input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtqlM.png)

EDIT:

First of all thanks for your answer, I would like to add more detail on what I am trying to do.
So I made a segmentation model which detects cracks in concrete (they can be any shape, vertical, horizontal, diagonal, etc) and now I need to identify their max-width and draw a line that shows where it occurs.

I found that the medial axis returns the distance from the boundary and by filtering max value I was able to get the width (see colab below) and its coordinate on the medial axis. Now I need to draw a line connecting the width between boundaries, but I have no idea on how to find the coordinates of such a line.

I thought of an algorithm which starts at the point of max distance occurrence on medial axis and expands until it finds a boundary, but I don't know how to implement it.

This image shows what I need to have:

[image]

[image]

After I find x and y of points I will be able to calculate euclidean distance between 2 points

```
dist=sqrt((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2)
```

Please look at my code in colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NvEyfrxpKGJ1kxjP48PGNB_UUSp6f6Ze?usp=sharing

sample input images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b5Mu.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPiHM.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMpxX.jpg

Comment: There is too much missing information in your code to run it, eg what is `filters.threshold_otsu(im)`? Are `image_path` & `img_path` two different things or is that a typo? Please include all `imports`, dont assume we know where you have got methods from.

Comment: The solution (and its complexity) depends on how precise the result has to be. Imagine your skeleton line as a continuously differentiable curve. Then the gradient of the curve and the orthogonal line at each point have to be interpolated, distances by geometric mean. Or do you just want to count pixels and switch between angles at 0, 45, and 90 deg? Can the boundary be more complex than in your example, e.g. bended like a horse shoe? Perhaps you want to add some more details in your question?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I provided more information in post above, hope it clarifies a bit more and you will be able to help

Comment: Medial, not medical !

Comment: Ahh OK that makes more sense, something you might want to research are things like [Mean Inercept Length or Star Length Distribution](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13517592_Star_length_distribution_A_volume-based_concept_for_the_characterization_of_structural_anisotropy) which are used in medical imaging for the same kind of problem. Nowadays they're used in 3D but the the methods can be simplified for 2D. With MIL & SLD you wouldnt have to skeletonize or find boundaries, you just threshold your image.

Comment: @kniemiec, I've simplified the determination of the gap's end points in my answer. Please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your approach using the medial axis function you can

- interpolate the direction of the axis at the point that was found
- derive the orthogonal from the direction
- look where the orthogonal reaches the boundary.

The example below shows the principle and works with your example images. But I'm sure there will be some boundary conditions that are not yet considered. I leave it to you to get it robust against real live data.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis
from skimage import img_as_ubyte

delta = 3  # delta index for interpolation

# get crack
im = cv2.imread("img.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)  # rgb just for demo purpose
_, crack = cv2.threshold(im, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# get medial axis
medial, distance = medial_axis(im, return_distance=True)
med_img = img_as_ubyte(medial)
med_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(med_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(rgb, med_contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
med_pts = [v[0] for v in med_contours[0]]

# get point with maximal distance from medial axis
max_idx = np.argmax(distance)
max_pos = np.unravel_index(max_idx, distance.shape)
max_dist = distance[max_pos]
coords = np.array([max_pos[1], max_pos[0]])
print(f"max distance from medial axis to boundary = {max_dist} at {coords}")

# interpolate orthogonal of medial axis at coords
idx = next(i for i, v in enumerate(med_pts) if (v == coords).all())
px1, py1 = med_pts[(idx-delta) % len(med_pts)]
px2, py2 = med_pts[(idx+delta) % len(med_pts)]
orth = np.array([py1 - py2, px2 - px1]) * max(im.shape)

# intersect orthogonal with crack and get contour
orth_img = np.zeros(crack.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.line(orth_img, coords + orth, coords - orth, color=255, thickness=1)
gap_img = cv2.bitwise_and(orth_img, crack)
gap_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gap_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
gap_pts = [v[0] for v in gap_contours[0]]

# determine the end points of the gap contour by negative dot product
n = len(gap_pts)
gap_ends = [
    p for i, p in enumerate(gap_pts)
    if np.dot(p - gap_pts[(i-1) % n], gap_pts[(i+1) % n] - p) < 0
]
print(f"Maximum gap found from {gap_ends[0]} to {gap_ends[1]}")
cv2.line(rgb, gap_ends[0], gap_ends[1], color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=1)

cv2.imwrite("test_out.png", rgb)
```

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I am coming back to you with a question:
assuming we have point on medial axis with greatest distance to the boundary, for example its [100 100] and distance of 3,4. Is there a way to find exact coordinates of this point which is in max distance?

Comment: Hm, not sure I get your point. Is it because the medial axis approach is not always  returning the exact point? Do you have an example were it fails? Perhaps you can create a new question and link it here?

Comment: Your solution works fine but there are some images where "coords" is not in "med_pts" and I don't know why (error -> https://imgur.com/xEA3g9k) (image where it occurs -> https://imgur.com/w4KHE4l).

And coming back to my question, in your code, "coords" is point on medial axis where boundary-axis distance is the greatest. 

I am wondering if there is a similar way to find coordinates of that point on the boundary which distance from medial axis you calculated, 
for example:

Comment: point on medial axis with greatest distance to boundary: [100,100]..

 distance: 5 ..

coords of the point which distance from meidal axis =5 : [x,y]?

Comment: Regarding the error: findContours returns a list of contours. In your image the crack is interrupted, so for each part a contour is returned. My answer only considers the first. Regarding the boundary: Still not clear. The points on the boundary that are at the end of the red line are printed out: "Maximum gap found from ... to ..."

Answer (score 1):

First thing I did was keep your images greyscale, there is no need to covert to 3 channels to find contours. Second was to convert the `boundary` image to a binary so that it is the same as the `skeleton` image. Then I simply added the two to get the `both` image.

I then clocked through each row (as you are looking for perpendicular distances) of the combined `both` image & looked for elements that where `True` i.e that are either boundary or skeleton pixels. I made a simplifying assumption at this point - I only searched for cases where there is a boundary followed by a *single* skeleton pixel then by a second boundary, I appreciate that this may not always be the case but I leave that particular headache for you to sort out.

After that its just a case of keeping track of he max & min distances recorded as you go through the image row by row. (edit: there maybe a cleaner way to do this than the way I've done it but hopefully you get the idea)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from skimage import filters
from skimage import morphology


def get_skeleton(image_path):

    im       = cv2.imread(image_path , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    binary   = im > filters.threshold_otsu(im)
    skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(binary)
    
    return skeleton


def get_boundary(image_path):
    
    reading_Img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    canny_Img   = cv2.Canny(reading_Img, 90, 100)
    contours,_  = cv2.findContours(canny_Img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    canvas      = np.zeros_like(reading_Img)
    boundary    = cv2.drawContours(canvas, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    binary      = boundary > filters.threshold_otsu(boundary)
    
    return binary


skeleton = get_skeleton("LtqlM.png")
boundary = get_boundary("LtqlM.png")
both     = skeleton + boundary

max_dist = 0
min_dist = 100000

for idx in range(both.shape[0]): # counting through rows
    
    row   = both[idx, :]
    lines = np.where(row==True)[0]
    
    if len(lines) == 3:
        
        dist_1 = lines[1] - lines[0]
        dist_2 = lines[2] - lines[1]
        
        if (dist_1 > dist_2) and dist_1 > max_dist:
            max_dist = dist_1
            
        if (dist_2 > dist_1) and dist_2 > max_dist:
            max_dist = dist_2
            
        if (dist_1 < dist_2) and dist_1 < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist_1
            
        if (dist_2 < dist_1) and dist_2 < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist_2
  
print("Maximum distance = ", max_dist) 
print("Minimum distance = ", min_dist)      
plt.imshow(both)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I provided more information in post above

Answer (score 0):

From the pixel with the largest distance, you can explore concentric square layers, until you find a background pixel. Then find the background pixel with the shortest Euclidean distance on the last layer. The second endpoint is symmetrical.